# Faced error during testing with Jest and Enzyme in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I was learning how to test React app, that is, to test if props is assigned to component. Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";

import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<About />", () => {
  it("check the type of value", () => {
    const props = {
      copyright: "All rights reserved"
    };
    const footer = shallow(<Footer {...props} />);
    expect(footer.prop("copyright")).toBeString(); //Here the error is shown saying something is wrong with tobeString().
  });
});
```

**Footer component**

**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Footer.module.css";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
const Footer = ({ copyright }) => {
  return (
    <footer className={styles.footer}>
      <p>{copyright}</p>
    </footer>
  );
};
Footer.propTypes = {
  copyright: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
export default Footer;
```

**

As you can see the code above in the first code block, tobeString() is said to be an ERROR

Comment: You can do something like `expect(typeof expected).toBe('string')`

Comment: @Ravi,thank you Ravi for your kind comments, Ravi, I have one question, before testing I have debugged my app and everything works as expected but I cannot get one thing why need to test if we did debugging and all works as expected? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `toBeString()` is a valid jest matcher.

You can try this instead:

```
expect(typeof footer.prop("copyright")).toBe('string');
```